# Select class of image within div for fadeIn with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div with two `img` tags in it. On click on the div I want to fadeIn the second img over the first one. I have several divs of this class and each has an img tag of the class `imgcarddiv` in it. I tried this, but nothing happens.

How can I adjust this code?

```
<div id="card1" class="carddiv">
        <img id="card1imgproxy" src="abc.gif"/>
        <img id="card1img" class="imgcarddiv" src="acespades.png" style="display: none"/>
    </div>    

$(".carddiv").click(function() {
    $("img", this).find(".imgcarddiv").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change to:

```js
$(".carddiv").click(function() {
  $(this).find(".imgcarddiv").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="card1" class="carddiv">
  <img id="card1imgproxy" src="abc.gif" />
  <img id="card1img" class="imgcarddiv" src="acespades.png" style="display: none" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your jquery selector is wrong since you want to find children of `.carddiv` you only need to use `$(this).find()`

```
$(".carddiv").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".imgcarddiv").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

if you are worried about other elements with the same `.imgcarddiv` class and only want to select images you can use:

```
    $(this).find("img.imgcarddiv").fadeIn("slow");
```

to narrow the find selector in selecting only `img` elements

**Check out the snippet below, when clicking img 1 it will `fadeIn` img 2**

```js
$(".carddiv").click(function() {
    $(this).find("img.imgcarddiv").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

```css
img { width:30px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="card1" class="carddiv">
        <img id="card1imgproxy" src="http://www.andlil.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/R%C3%A8gle-1.png"/>
        <img id="card1img" class="imgcarddiv" src="http://tomreynolds.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/2-graphic.png" style="display: none"/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$("img", this)` is `$(selector, context)` syntax which works like `$(context).find(selector)`. It returns all the `img` descendants. As `img` can't have `img` child, the `find` query will fail:

```
$(this).find('img')
       .find(".imgcarddiv") // returns an empty collection
       .fadeIn("slow"); // doesn't do anything
```

You should either use the the `filter` method for filtering the collection (images that have certain className):

```
$("img", this).filter(".imgcarddiv").fadeIn("slow");
```

Or remove the `find` call and use:

```
$("img.imgcarddiv", this).fadeIn("slow");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This is how I understand the code you've written.

```
$(".carddiv").click(function() {
// on click of carddiv div tag
    $("img", this).find(".imgcarddiv").fadeIn("slow");
    // fade in the second div
});
```

I don't love how this is written. My first thought is that the first image is still on top of the second image. I'd suggest the following changes (note that I prefer to reference the id rather than the class in the Jquery selector).

```
$("#card1").click(function() {
    $('#card1img').fadeIn("slow");
    $('#card1imgproxy').fadeOut('slow');
});
```